# Indexing ASYNC JavaScript content

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, search-engine, googlebot

Is there a technic existing to index AJAX content with google bot? I mean, is it possible to declare a method in javascript that the bot will call and execute to get page content?

Comment: yes, take a look here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: Thank Rick. I know this tecnique, but it's force my server to work and generate a lots of combinaison and rexecute a lot of server code. it's there another way ?

Comment: @RickLancee — That's a horrible hack that's been superseded by the standard `pushState` method.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The sensible approach to dealing with this is to create real pages that express the state of the document is in after being manipulated with JavaScript, to link to them as normal and then [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) with JavaScript to:

- [Cancel the normal action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) of the link
- [Modify the DOM](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML)
- [Change the URL in the address bar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)